# EIntOverflow in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, integer-overflow

I'm using this code. The `mod` line triggers an integer overflow (Delphi 7)

```
iValue : cardinal;
iWord : word;
...

if iValue mod iWord > 0 then 
...
```

As it is on a customer PC with no way to debug, I need some help to fix it.

Comment: not much we can say here, one or both of your variables has a value that causes this. Are you 100% sure the error happens on that line ? You need to reproduce it by trying with different values until you get the error, and then find a way around it.